# How to use SharedPreferences to save and retrive more than one old values?

Tags: java, android

I am very new for android. I am developing address app. I have two fragments (AddressFragment & AddAddressFragment).AddressFragment contains some edit text (line1,city,country,state). Once user filled all the details in AddressFragment and click save button means, its show alert with radio buttons(Home Address,Office Address,School Address etc.). If choose anyone option in radio button then Created list (Home Address,Office Address etc.) automatically in AddAddressFragment.

Whats my problem is, if i click anyone (Home Address) from list in AddAddressFragment means i want to show whatever user stored in Home Address. But,I can retrieve only recently stored address.

How to retrieve previously stored items.

Please anyone help me!

My code here:

AddressFragment.java:

```
SharedPreferences shared = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Addresses", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shared.edit();
                        editor.putString("AddressDetails",line1.getText().toString()+"|||"+line2.getText().toString()+"|||"
                                +cityText.getText().toString()
                                +"|||"+zipcode.getText().toString()+"|||"+country.getSelectedItem().toString()
                                +"|||"+state.getSelectedItem().toString()+"|||"+landmark.getText().toString());
                        editor.commit();
```

AddAddressFragment.java:

```
SharedPreferences shared = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Addresses", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String[] values = shared.getString("AddressDetails", "").split("\\|\\|\\|");
        Log.d("Values:", Arrays.toString(values));

            Log.d("Line 1:",values[0]);
            Log.d("Line 2:",values[1]);
            Log.d("City:",values[2]);
            Log.d("Zipcode:",values[3]);
            Log.d("Country:",values[4]);
            Log.d("State:",values[5]);
            Log.d("Landmark:",values[6]);
```

Comment: I'm not sure SharedPreferences would be the most appropriate way to save this data. If you are trying to store multiple addresses, you are better off using the included SQLite database packages. SharedPreferences would only be appropriate if you were storing the user's address as part of customizing the app.

Answer (score 0):

I think that storing the adresses in SharedPreferences is a very bad idea. There are a lot of better ways to store such data, like the SQLite way:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

A relational database is what you want to store your adresses. Just create the table like **(id, adress, zip, housenumber, adressType)**

adressType will indicate if it is office, home and so on.

You can then just write each adress into the table and retrieve them using a simple query like

```
Select * from adresses
```

or filter them by adressType.

I really recommend that you take a look at SQLite and relational databses